# Application UI is not receiving all data from high speed socket

Tags: android, sockets, switch-statement, data-management

Aim: Get the data from socket and display in the android application.

What I did:

1. Socket connection is established.
2. Received data from socket.
3. Received socket data append to UI.//Hear I am getting problem. Because Socket is sending data high speed(500us).Some times application not able to append to UI.

Code:

```
InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
while ((din.read(socketData)) != '\0') {
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
          parsedData[i] = (int) (socketData[i]);
         }
clusterData = parsedData[4] | (parsedData[5] << 8);
Log.d("AAA","data0-->"+clusterData+"   data1--->"+parsedData[5])
new CustomTask().execute((Void[]) null);
}

private class CustomTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... param) {
            //Do some work
            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {

            switch (dataId) {
                case MwDataIDs.CAN_BUS_M2A_CAR_SPEED:
                    Log.d("AAA","data_speed--->"+clusterData+"id--->"+dataId);
                      ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(aaa, "rotation", clusterData).start();                      
                    break;
               case MwDataIDs.CAN_BUS_M2A_CAR_RPM:
                       ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(bbb, "rotation", clusterData/25).start();
```

}

```
   Log:
   09-19 09:25:43.616  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->43   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.626  2028  2028 D AAA     : data_speed--->105id--->43
   09-19 09:25:43.628  2028  2028 D AAA     : data_speed--->105id--->43
   09-19 09:25:43.639  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->74   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.640  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->64   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.662  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->75   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.716  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->43   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.739  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->76   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.739  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->64   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.764  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->77   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.764  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->43   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.787  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->78   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.787  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->64   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.811  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->79   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.812  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->43   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.835  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->80   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.836  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->64   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.859  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->81   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.859  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->43   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.879  2028  2028 D AAA     : data_speed--->101id--->43
   09-19 09:25:43.879  2028  2028 D AAA     : data_speed--->101id--->43
   09-19 09:25:43.884  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->82   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.884  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->64   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.907  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->83   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.907  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->43   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.919  2028  2028 D AAA     : data_speed--->100id--->43
   09-19 09:25:43.920  2028  2028 D AAA     : data_speed--->100id--->43
   09-19 09:25:43.932  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->84   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.932  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->64   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.955  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->85   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.956  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->43   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.960  2028  2028 D AAA     : data_speed--->99id--->43
   09-19 09:25:43.960  2028  2028 D AAA     : data_speed--->99id--->43
   09-19 09:25:43.979  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->86   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:43.980  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->64   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:44.003  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->87   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:44.005  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->43   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:44.027  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->88   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:44.027  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->64   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:44.051  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->89   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:44.052  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->43   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:44.075  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->90   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:44.075  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->64   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:44.099  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->91   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:44.100  2028  2054 D AAA     : data0-->43   data1--->0
   09-19 09:25:44.120  2028  2028 D AAA     : data_speed--->96id--->43
   09-19 09:25:44.120  2028  2028 D AAA     : data_speed--->96id--->43
```

In the logcat, If data0 is 43 then it should call MwDataIDs.CAN_BUS_M2A_CAR_SPEED switch case.Randomly if Data0 value is 43, its not going to switch case. 
I could not able to understand why its not going to switch condition.

Comment: what does `din.read(socketData)` return?

Comment: Thanks for your reply . din.read(socketData) is check for socket data NULL or not.

Comment: NULL or not? what NULL? did you read the [InputStream#read()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream#read(byte[])) documentation?

Comment: looping the condition up-to null.Like socket is sending 6 bytes.After 6 bytes exit from the loop

Comment: did you read what `InputStream#read(byte[])` method returns? if so, what it returns? does it return `'\0'`?

Comment: yes,I am reading byes from socket.

Comment: i gave you a link [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream#read(byte%5B%5D)), did you read it, did you?

Comment: Yes I read.  InputStream#read(byte[]) returns 6

Comment: so why are you calling `for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)`? and why are you comparing that return value to `'\0'`?

Comment: now i have changed to while((read = din.read(socketData, 0, socketData.length)) != -1) and for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++).

Comment: what `6`? you have `read` variable, dont you?

Comment: yes we have , for (int i = 0; i < socketData.length; i++) {

Comment: i said: `read` variable - that variable which stores number of bytes read...

Comment: changed to for (int i = 0; i < read; i++)    .   when we are append data to UI(switch case) then only problem is raised.

Comment: `"then only problem is raised."` meaning what?

Comment: I mean that. I can able receive the data from socket. Sometimes data is not appending UI. I have updated log-file in the question.For Example data0 is 43 then it should call switch case.but its not happening in all times.